# Calculate checksum in C#

Tags: c#, math, calculus

```
numbers[i] = numbers[i] * 2;

if (numbers[i] >= 10)
{
   string t = numbers[i].ToString();
   Console.WriteLine(t[0] + " plus " + t[1]+" = "+quersumme(t).ToString());
   numbers[i] = Convert.ToInt32(t[0]) + Convert.ToInt32(t[1]);
}

public int quersumme(string n)
{
   return n[0] + n[1];
}
```

The function returns 101 when I enter 7. But 7 * 2 = 14 and quersumme should do 1+4 = 5

Comment: What's the question o-O

Comment: What is it you actually want to do?

Comment: You're taking the Char value you should char.GetNumericValue() instead.

Comment: Subjectively, it must be more elegant to avoid the use of `string` and `char` altogether. http://stackoverflow.com/a/15505378/659190

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`t[0]` is the character '1', and `t[1]` is the character '4', which is translated to 49 + 52, hence 101. Check out an [ASCII chart](http://www.asciitable.com/) to see what I'm talking about.

You could try using the [Char.GetNumericValue()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.getnumericvalue.aspx) function:

```
return (int)Char.GetNumericValue(n[0]) + (int)Char.GetNumericValue(n[1]);
```

Comment: I thought about ASCII and even looked it up but seems like I missed the essential bit in the table. Thanks dude!

Answer (score 5):

You're currently summing the Unicode code points - '1' is 49, and '4' is 52, hence the 101. You want to take the digit value of each character.

If you *know* that the digits will be in the range '0'-'9', the simplest way of doing that is just to subtract '0' and to use the LINQ `Sum` method to sum each value:

```
public int SumDigits(string n)
{
   return n.Sum(c => c - '0');
}
```

Or you could use `Char.GetNumericValue()`, but that returns `double` because it also copes with characters such as U+00BD: ½.

Comment: @Jodrell: Well, sort of. You can definitely do it without. On the other hand, as it's about *digits*, you could argue it's about a textual representation of the number.

Answer (score 0):

Try converting n[0] and n[1] to separate int32's in your quersomme function

Comment: Converting to int32 will give character value again!

Answer (score 0):

You are doing string concatenation in quesumme method.

Should be:

```
public int quersumme(string n)
{
   return (int)Char.GetNumericValue(n[0]) + (int)Char.GetNumericValue(n[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you are trying to enumerate the digits in an `int`.

Try this to avoid slow and cumbersome parsing and conversion. (Its all relative, I haven't tested performance.)

```
static IEnumerable<int> EnumerateDigits(int value, int baseValue = 10)
{
    while (value > 0)
    {
        yield return value % baseValue;
        value = value / baseValue
    }
}
```

Then, if you want to switch the order into an array

```
var t = EnumerateDigits(numbers[i]).Reverse().ToArray();
```

---

But, if you just want to sum the digits.

```
var checksum = EnumerateDigits(numbers[i]).Sum()
```